# finding records with cursors and procedures

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, procedure

[image: my diagrams for the libaray project]

i dont kno whow to write a proper procedure wtih cursors. i am doing somehtings wring ?

```
procedure1: for given student show all titles of books he ever rented
--no such student  no recordsexcep

    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
create or replace procedure showRENTS(v_idStudent int)
as

v_NameOfBook varchar2(100);
--v_count int;
no_such_id EXCEPTION;
cursor c1 is
select NameOfbook from book
where 
begin 
open c1;
loop 
fetch c1
into v_fname,v_lname;
--select count(1) into v_count from Student where idStduent =v_id ;
--if
--v_count = 0;
--then raise no_such_id;
--end if;
exit when c1%notfounf
end loop; 
close c1;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see images, but - procedure you posted can be rewritten to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE showrents (v_idstudent IN INT)
AS
BEGIN
   FOR c1 IN (SELECT nameofbook FROM book)
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (c1.nameofbook);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I'd suggest you to use cursor FOR loop - it is simpler to write & maintain as Oracle does most of job for you (you don't have to declare cursor variable, open the cursor, fetch from it, take care about exiting the loop, closing the cursor).

I'm not sure what its parameter has to do with it but I left it; I guess you'll add some code later.

I hope it'll get you started.

Answer (score 0):

For issues like this just follow your ERD. So here your given a student is and asked for the book rented. Follow the path: Student -> Process -> Copies -> Book. It actually becomes a fairly easy query.

````
    create or replace procedure showrents(v_idStudent int)
    as
        no_such_id EXCEPTION;
        v_student_ok interger :=0;  
        cursor c_student_books is 
               select nameofbook 
                 from student s
                 join process p on (p.idstudent = s.idstudent)
                 join copies  c on (c.idcopies  = p.idcopies)
                 join books   b on (b.idbook    = b.idbook)
                where s.idstudent = v_idStudent;
    begin 
        select count(*)
          into v_student_ok
          from student 
         where idstudent = v_idstudent
           and rownum <= 1;
           
        if v_student_ok = 0 
        then
           raise no_such_id;
        end if;
    
        for rented in c_student_books
        loop 
           dbms_output.put_line( rented.nameofBook);
        end ;
    end showrents; ```
````